# Kong - remove a service

Tags: kong

Is there any way to remove a service from kong's database.

Right now when I am running an instance again I am getting the `unique constraint error` from kong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the admin API, just use `DELETE` on `/services/` with id or name

For example to delete the service with id `0f32ae39-d338-4074-a112-c5106c99776d`

```sh
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8001/services/0f32ae39-d338-4074-a112-c5106c99776d
```

To delete the service with name `serviceFoo`

```sh
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8001/services/serviceFoo
```